# Jstree problem when using refresh_node in a non-root node

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm using jstree to show a few nodes (incl. DnD, Type and Contextmenu plugins).
I'm getting the whole tree with no problems, showing it properly and I can select any node, but, after using an update operation (by an Ajax call to server) on one node, I want to refresh this (and only this) node. refresh_node(myNode) operation is what I want, and Ajax call is working ok and gives me only the subtree part I need.

But, when jstree tries to redraw, I get an error about a nonexistent variable. I debugged it and I noted that parents array of some nodes has dissapeared.

I'm using the alternate JSON format to load my tree, with this config:

```
core{
    multiple: false,
    data {
        url: "my_url_string_to_server",
        data: function(node) { return { id: nodeId, /*other params*/ } }
    }
}
/*other plugins config*/
```

and my call to refresh_node:

```
//nodeId is a string with the name of the node I want to refresh.
var node = $.jstree.reference('.tree-data').get_node(nodeId);
$.jstree.reference('.tree-data').refresh_node(node);
//I tried refresh_node(nodeId) too, with the same error result.
```

All my tree nodes are:
    { 
        "id", "UniqueId",
        "parent": "Parent" },
        "text", "Name" },
        "state": { },
        "type": "type"
        "li_attr": {
            { "title", "title" },
            { "class", "class" }
        }
        "a_attr": {
            { "class", "class" }
        },
        "data": {
            { "dbid", "Id" },
            { "dbparent", "ParentId" },
            { "status", "statusId" }
        }
    }

as stated in jstree documentation [(see 'alternative JSON format')](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)

returning a list of them (required node an all children) as a result of the ajax call (doesn't care whether is a call for root node or another non-root node)

Please, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thankyou so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue: when you call with an id other than root id ("#"), refresh deal with child nodes of node id. My method was returning root node and child nodes, which is wrong. There is no functions to update a single node directly from DB, but [this](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1763) issue shows how to update them from js, so, I'll try to update them by getting new status through an ajax call and use that response to update all data and redraw manually.

Hope this can be useful for others.

Thankyou all!